# Auto-submit of a hidden reCAPTCHA form does not work

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse" />
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary display-2" id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" >continue</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

I've tried this and it does not work:

```
<script>document.getElementById('submit').submit();</script>
```

Comment: Your HTML is ***very*** malformed.  The first thing you should do is correct the HTML structure.  Using a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/) can help with that.  Aside from that, *buttons* don't have `submit` events, *forms* do.  There's also no element in your HTML with the `id` of `"submit"`.

Comment: im beginner thats why thanks for information

Comment: Are you attempting to submit a recaptcha response?  What version of recaptcha are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is enough to go on here, but it seems you are attempting to submit a reCAPTCHA response.  If this is true then you should make sure you are following the recommendations in the [reCAPTCHA documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro).

Outside of their recommendations, it would seem the simplest way to get `document.getElementById()` to work would be to target the `myForm` id on the form itself (since forms have a `submit` event as @David pointed out).  This is what the `getElementById()` would look like in that case:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').submit()
```